# CUDA: cudaMemcpyToSymbol is not copying data

Tags: cuda

I am having problems using cudaMemcpyToSymbol. I have a code that works just fine. A cutdown version of my code is this:

```
mykernel.h file:
__global__ 
void foo(float* out);
```

---

```
mykernel.cu file:
#include "kernels.h"
__global__ 
void foo(float* out)
{
    uint32_t idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    out[idx] = 10;
}
```

---

```
main.cu file:
#include "kernels.h"
main()
{
    // initialization and declaration stuff here

    foo<<<1,1,1>>>(my_global_memory);

    // read back global memory and investigate values
}
```

The above code works just perfect. Now I want to replace this "10" value with a value coming from a constant memory. So what I did was to:

- add `__constant__ float my_const_var;` in mykernel.h file.
- replace the last line of my kernel with `out[idx] = my_const_var;` in mykenel.cu
- add `float value = 10.0f; cudaMemcpyToSymbol(my_const_var,&value);` before my invocation in main.cu

After having done all that it looks like cudaMemcpyToSymbol doesn't copy the actual value because I get a result of '0' instead of '10'. In addition, I always check for CUDA errors and  there is none. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? And why cudaMemcpyToSymbol does not copy the value to the symbol? I am using a GeForce9600M (compute capability 1.1) with latest drivers on Debian Linux and CUDA SDK 5.0. I also tried running cuda-memcheck and I get no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are attempting to access a variable in one compilation unit that is defined in another compilation unit,  (`main.cu` and `mykernel.cu`) this will require [separate device compilation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda).

> Prior to the 5.0 release, CUDA did not support separate compilation, so CUDA code could not call device functions or *access variables across files*.

Unfortunately, separate compilation is only available for devices of compute capability 2.0 or greater.

> Separate compilation only works for sm_20 and above,

You can work around this for pre-cc2.0 by putting all your CUDA code that must reference a given variable in the same file (the same file where the variable is declared).

Comment: I have to say that I wasn't aware of that. Excellent, now it works.