# Issue regarding data of constant memory in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I have a CUDA application where I am trying to use constant memory. But when I am writing the kernel in the same file where the main function is, then only the data in the constant memory is getting recognized inside the kernel. Otherwise if I declare the kernel function in some other file then the constant memory is becoming 0 and the operation is operating properly. I am providing a simple dummy code which would explain the problem more easily. This program have a 48x48 matrix divided into 16x16 blocks and I am storing random numbers 1 to 50 in it. Inside the kernel I am adding numbers stored in constant memory to the each rows in a block. The code is given below :

**Header File:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cutil.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

__constant__ int test_cons[16];

__global__ void test_kernel_1(int *,int *);
```

**Main Program :**

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{   int *mat,*dev_mat,*res,*dev_res;
    int i,j;
    int test[16 ]   = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(test_cons,test,16*sizeof(int));
    mat = (int *)malloc(48*48*sizeof(int));
    res = (int *)malloc(48*48*sizeof(int));
    memset(res,0,48*48*sizeof(int));

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<48;i++)
    {   for(j=0;j<48;j++)
        {   mat[i*48+j] = rand()%(50-1)+1;
            printf("%d\t",mat[i*48+j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_mat,48*48*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_mat,mat,48*48*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_res,48*48*sizeof(int));

    dim3 gridDim(48/16,48/16,1);
    dim3 blockDim(16,16,1);

    test_kernel_1<<< gridDim,blockDim>>>(dev_mat,dev_res);

    cudaMemcpy(res,dev_res,48*48*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<48;i++)
    {   for(j=0;j<48;j++)
        {   printf("%d\t",res[i*48+j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    cudaFree(dev_mat);
    cudaFree(dev_res);
    free(mat);
    free(res);
    exit(0);
}
```

**Kernel Function :**

```
__global__ void test_kernel_1(int *dev_mat,int* dev_res)
{
    int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x +threadIdx.x;

    dev_res[row*48+col] = dev_mat[row*48+col] + test_cons[threadIdx.x];
}
```

Now when I am declaring the kernel function inside the main program file along with the main program then the constant memory values are correct otherwise if it is in a different file the `test_cons[threadIdx.x]` values are becoming 0.

I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997611/cuda-writing-to-constant-memory-wrong-value) which kind of discuss the same problem but I am not getting it properly. It would be very much helpful if someone could tell me why this is happening and what I need to do avoid this problem. Any sort of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have answered your own question with the link you have provided. The link exactly says how to solve your problem. You have to declare a wrapper in main file and call that wrapper from the file where you have the kernel to copy the values into the constant memory.

Comment: Yeah I kind of understand that the link actually answers my question but it would be helpful if you could write the necessary codes in the program I have provided and then post it as answer. I am not able to understand the link totally. Thanks

Comment: I did something mentioned in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450556/allocate-constant-memory

but it is still not working. I am not totally understanding how the wrapper would be done to avoid the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recently answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921729/cuda-cudamemcpytosymbol-is-not-copying-data/18921973#18921973)

CUDA can handle code that references device code (entry points) or symbols in other files, but it requires separate compilation with device linking (as described and linked in the link I gave above).  (And separate compilation/linking requires CC 2.0 or greater)

So if you modify the link steps you can have your `__constant__` variable in a given file, and reference it from a different file.

If not (if you don't specify separate compilation and device linking), then the device code that references the `__constant__` variable, the host code that references the `__constant__` variable, and the definition/declaration of the variable itself, all need to be in the *same file*.

So this:

```
__constant__ int test_cons[16];
```

This:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(test_cons,test,16*sizeof(int));
```

And this:

```
dev_res[row*48+col] = dev_mat[row*48+col] + test_cons[threadIdx.x];
```

all need to be in the same file.

Comment: I did exactly the same you have mentioned. I declared the constant variable, cudaMemcpyToSymbol and kernel statement in the same file. But it is still not working. I did the cudaMemcpyToSymbol in a function which I am calling from the main function, declared __constant__ and kernel, all three in the same file but it is still not working.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the the example where you are doing everything in a single file.  I don't see that you are doing any [cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) in what you have posted so far.  I took the 3 different pieces of code you have posted so far, put them all in the same file, and it seemed to compile and run successfully for me.  For instance the first 3 numbers in the data were 2 28 17 and the first 3 numbers in the results were 3 30 20 etc.

Comment: Actually there I was missing something in the main function and I corrected it. Now it is working fine and giving the correct result. I have accepted the answer after it started working properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is totally acceptable I am adding this since the user is not able to make it working. You can accept the above answer this is just for your reference.

Kernel.cu file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__constant__ int test_cons[16];

void copymemory (int *test)
{
      cudaMemcpyToSymbol(test_cons,test,16*sizeof(int));
}

__global__ void test_kernel_1(int *dev_mat,int* dev_res)
{
    int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x +threadIdx.x;

    if (threadIdx.x ==0)
    {
        printf ("testcons[0] is %d\n", test_cons[threadIdx.x]) ;
    }
    dev_res[row*48+col] = dev_mat[row*48+col] + test_cons[threadIdx.x];
 }
```

simple.cu file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>


void copymemory (int *temp) ;

__global__ void test_kernel_1(int *,int *);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int *mat,*dev_mat,*res,*dev_res;
    int i,j;
    int test[16 ]   = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    mat = (int *)malloc(48*48*sizeof(int));
    res = (int *)malloc(48*48*sizeof(int));
    memset(res,0,48*48*sizeof(int));


    copymemory (test) ;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<48;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<48;j++)
            {
                mat[i*48+j] = rand()%(50-1)+1;
                //printf("%d\t",mat[i*48+j] );
            }
            //printf("\n");
    }

    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_mat,48*48*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_mat,mat,48*48*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_res,48*48*sizeof(int));
    dim3 gridDim(48/16,48/16,1);
    dim3 blockDim(16,16,1);

    test_kernel_1<<< gridDim,blockDim>>>(dev_mat,dev_res);
    cudaMemcpy(res,dev_res,48*48*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for(i=0;i<48;i++)
    {
           for(j=0;j<48;j++)
            {
                    //   printf("%d\t",res[i*48+j] );
            }
            //printf("\n");
    }

    cudaFree(dev_mat);
    cudaFree(dev_res);
    free(mat);
    free(res);
    exit(0);
}
```

I have commented your printf. And the printf in the kernel prints the value 1. I also tested by changing the value of test[0] in main function and it works perfectly.